# Need help to use Controller

Tags: extjs

I'm trying to use controller in my program.Controller name is "Main" and code is given below.

```
refs: [
{
ref: 'navigation',
selector: 'navigation'
},
{
ref: 'ContentPanel',      
selector: 'ContentPanel'
},
{
ref: 'viewport',        
selector: 'viewport'
}
]
```

and i have a view port with following code.

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.MyViewport', {
extend: 'Ext.container.Viewport',

requires: [
'MyApp.view.Header',
'MyApp.view.Navigation',
'MyApp.view.ContentPanel'
],

layout: {
type: 'border'
},

initComponent: function() {
var me = this;

Ext.applyIf(me, {
items: [
{
xtype: 'header',
height: 136,
region: 'north'
},
{
xtype: 'navigation',
width: 207,
region: 'west'
},
{
xtype: 'ContentPanel',
width: 431,
flex: 2,
region: 'center'
}
]
});
```

now my problem is i have to get an object of ContentPanel when i click on naviagation(tree panel). i tried using

```
var content= this.getContentPanel();
```

i have one more form panel add i want to add that to the controller. and i want to get the instance of the form and put it inside the content panel and display.

```
 var form= this.getMyform();// i didnt add Myform to the controller yet because i dont    know to add reference properly
 content.add(form);
```

My main problem is that i cant instantiate the content panel and form in ItemClick event of navigation(tree panel)

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A ref should start with a lower case letter. The same is valid for xtypes. `ref: 'contentPanel'` will define a getter `getContentPanel`. Since `contentPanel`is different from `ContentPanel`, I'm not sure, if in your case the getter is created or not.

Comment: Hi Lorenz, i got "this.GetContentPanel();" properly.and still my ref is "ContentPanel".

Comment: can you plz tell me what is ref, selector and xtype means in controller??

Comment: Ask this in a new question. I think the answer will be long. The two are related closely to each other.